# JS. How to copy array object per each prop

Tags: javascript

**Limitations:**

1. I am limited to *not* using ES6 syntax
2. I need a way to do this without knowing the exact properties of the object. So without manually adding `id`, and `name` when pushing to the `desiredOutput` array, but rather copying all the properties automatically.

**I have:**
*an array with one object which has multiple, unique, `props`*

```
var items = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "item name",
    props: [
      {
        propId: 1,
        propName: "name one"
      }, 
      {
        propId: 2,
        propName: "name two"
      },
      {
        propId: 3,
        propName: "name three"
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

**Desired outcome:**
*a new array that contains **one** copy of the original object inside the array, **per each** `prop`*

```
var desiredOutput = [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "item name",
      props: [
        {
          propId: 1,
          propName: "name one"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "item name",
      props: [
        {
          propId: 2,
          propName: "name two"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "item name",
      props: [
        {
          propId: 3,
          propName: "name three"
        }
      ]
    }
  ];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
function copyProps(itemsArr) {
  var copy = []; var i = 0;
  
  itemsArr.forEach(function(item) {
    item.props.forEach(function(prop) {
      copy[i] = Object.assign({}, item);
      copy[i].props = [Object.assign({}, prop)];
      i++;
    });
  }); 
  
  return copy;
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this if I don't know the exact properties of the object? So without manually adding "id", and "name" when pushing to the `copy` array, but rather copying all the properties automatically.

Comment: @Aerra
You can do `copy[i] = Object.assign(item); copy[i].prop = [Object.assign({}, prop)]; i++`
This way, you copy the `item` object, and override the `prop` property

Comment: This seems to only be copying the third prop, I'm not sure why. Here's a jsbin link: https://jsbin.com/felepoc/edit?js,console

Comment: @Aerra got the issue, i've updated my answer
Refer to this fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/hp6yauo3/

Answer (score 2):

**Logic**

- Loop through keys each item in items array.
- Check if the key name is not `props`.
- Add the key value combination to an object except for key `props`
- Loop through the `props` node in each object.
- Add each prop to `props` key and push it to final array
- You should perform a deep copy logic here, sice you are keep on updating the pushong object

```js
var items = [{
  id: 1,
  name: "item name",
  props: [
    { propId: 1, propName: "name one" }, 
    { propId: 2, propName: "name two" },
    { propId: 3, propName: "name three" }
  ]
}];
var desiredOutput = [];
for (var index = 0; index < items.length; index++) {
  var outputNode = {};
  var entries = Object.entries(items[index]);
  for(var innerIndex = 0; innerIndex < entries.length; innerIndex++) {
    if(entries[innerIndex][0] !== 'props') {
      outputNode[entries[innerIndex][0]] = entries[innerIndex][1];
    }
  }
  for(var innerIndex = 0; innerIndex < items[index].props.length; innerIndex++) {
    outputNode.props = [items[index].props[innerIndex]];
    // This is mandatory to perform deep copy
    desiredOutput.push(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(outputNode)));
  }
}
console.log(desiredOutput);
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this if I don't know the exact properties of the object? So without manually adding "id", and "name" when pushing to the `desiredOutput` array, but rather copying all the properties automatically.

Comment: @Aerra Its possible. Check the updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

just another way of getting the desired output with deep copy.

```
var items = [{
  id: 1,
  name: "item name",
  props: [{
    propId: 1,
    propName: "name one"
  }, {
    propId: 2,
    propName: "name two"
  }, {
    propId: 3,
    propName: "name three"
  }]
}];

var desiredOutput = [];

function ExtractDataFromProp(jsObject, jsObjectPropKey) {
    if (Object.hasOwnProperty.call(jsObject, jsObjectPropKey)) {
        const propElementValue = jsObject[jsObjectPropKey];
        if (typeof propElementValue != "object") {
            const propString = `"${jsObjectPropKey}" : ${isNaN(propElementValue) ? ("\"" + propElementValue + "\"") : propElementValue}`;
            return propString;
        }
        return null;
    }
}

items.forEach((item) => {
    var itemObjArray = [];
    var itemProps = [];

    for (const itemKey in item)
        itemObjArray.push(ExtractDataFromProp(item, itemKey));

    item.props.forEach((prop) => {
        for (const propKey in prop)
            itemProps.push(ExtractDataFromProp(prop, propKey));

        var finalObject = `{ ${itemObjArray.join(',').replace(/,\s*$/, "")}, "props": { ${itemProps.join(',').replace(/,\s*$/, "")} } }` //

        desiredOutput.push(JSON.parse(finalObject))

    });
});

console.dir(desiredOutput);
```